# Какое правильное окончание слова "расположенное" в данном случае?

Tags: окончания

«В соответствии с условиями настоящего Договора Продавец передает в собственность Покупателю недвижимое имущество (далее по тексту – Имущество): подстанция 110/35/6 кВ (без ЗРУ-6 кВ), расположенное(ая) по адресу: Иркутская область, г. Свирск, инвентарный номер 941737, кадастровый номер 38:43:00045:462, а Покупатель принимает и оплачивает его стоимость».

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, правильно так: *подстанц**ию**... расположенн**ую** по адресу.* "Оплачивает **его** стоимость" надо, по-моему, оставить как есть. Не силён в правилах составления договоров, но интуиция и то, что мне попадалось, подсказывают, что в конечном счёте речь должна идти об общем — Имуществе. Пояснили, какое именно Имущество, но дальше говорим о нём без уточнений.

А вот двух двоеточий подряд надо постараться избежать. Предлагаю  переписать так:

> *...недвижимое имущество (далее по тексту – Имущество), а именно подстанцию 110/35/6 кВ (без ЗРУ-6 кВ), расположенную по адресу: Иркутская область...*

Answer (score 1):

Если соблюдать принятый канцелярский стиль (позиции списка перечисляется в именительном падеже), то "расположенная", ибо "по адресу" расположена **станция**, а не "имущество".
Впрочем, скорее всего такие вещи пишутся по шаблону, который есть у любого нотариуса. Всего вернее пойти по стандартному пути.

То, что предлагает **Артём Луговой**, - это все, конечно, хорошо, но для нормального литературного стиля, который терпеть не могут бюрократы. Поэтому, боюсь, придется как минимум сохранить именительный падеж. И тут жизнь вступает в некоторое противоречие с грамматическими и стилевыми рекомендациями.